# how to further simplify this matrix ?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, self-learning

I have the following matrix , can i smiplify this further ?

$$B=(Z^TZ)^{-1} + (Z^TZ)^{-1}Z^T( I - P_z)^{-1}Z(Z^TZ)^{-1} $$

Where $Z$ is a (n x 1 ) vector, $I$ is the identity matrix and

$P_z$ is the projection matrix of Z So $P_Z = Z(Z^TZ)^{-1}Z^T$.

Can i simplify this further ? Since $(Z^TZ)^{-1}$ is in the both sides of the second term , i dont know how to factor it out.

Thank you.

Comment: $Z^TZ$ is a scalar.

Comment: Won't $I-P_Z$ be a singular (and therefore non-invertible) matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Since $Z^TZ$ is a scalar, you can write $$B=(Z^TZ)^{-1}(I-(Z^TZ)^{-1}Z^T(I-P_z)^{-1}Z)$$